# VF Rerender auto-normalizes spaces in Text fields. Why?

Tags: visualforce, bug, inputtext, form

I am quite sure that I have not seen this behavior before. So it might be a platform bug (or feature).

This page below displays 3 text fields that are bound to an Accounts text field. If the user clicks the button the form is rerendered without calling any Apex logic.

When you type `abc      def` (many spaces) in all three fields and click Rerender the spaces are normalized /stripped in all fields except the textarea.

Why is that so? Is this intended behaviour?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AccountNumber}" />
        <apex:inputText value="{!Account.AccountNumber}" />
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!Account.AccountNumber}" />

        <apex:commandButton rerender="form" value="Rerender form" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It is HTML behavior, not Visualforce. Text within a textarea tag is considered pre-formatted (so spaces are retained as they are), while in other inputs isn't. (Mine is just a guess, makes sense but I'm not sure if it's the correct reason for it.)

Comment: Can you please prove that this is HTML behavior by any reference link? Google didn't find any for me :-(

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp and http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/white-space-handling/. Basically most of elements in HTML have pre-defined the "white-space: normal" behavior, which collapses multiple adjacent spaces into one. It looks like textarea should have that too, but could be SF CSS specifies textareas to behave differently.

Comment: Collapsing Whitespace in p-Tags makes sense to me, but 2changing the content of form fields where 2 spaces might have a different semantic is not explained by your references. An I hope this is neighter a feature of HTML nor Salesforce.com.

Comment: I'm sorry because I should get at the bottom of things and answer with answers, not with traces to follow, but that would have required me to set-up a test case and I don't have time at the moment. I'll get back here during the day, if nobody comes up with a definitive solution :-) Ad maiora!

Answer (score 1):

I did a little experiment using this code + VF page to see if `style:"white-space-collapse: preserve"` had any affect

**Custom Controller using a custom object**

```
public class FooController {

    public String whiteSpaceTextField1  {get; set;}
    public String whiteSpaceTextField2  {get; set;}
    public Boolean preserveWhiteSpace   {get; set;}
    public Foo__c                       foo {get; set;}

    public FooController() {foo = new Foo__c(); preserveWhiteSpace = false;}        // constructor
    public void toggleWhiteSpace () {preserveWhiteSpace = !preserveWhiteSpace;}
}
```

**VF page**

```
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputText value="inputField bound to long textarea sobjFld"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!foo.longTextAreaFld__c}" style="IF(preserveWhiteSpace,'white-space-collapsing: preserve;','')"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputText value="inputField bound to text sobjFld "/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!foo.textfld__c}" style="IF(preserveWhiteSpace,'white-space-collapsing: preserve;','')"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You get a form that looks like this enabling toggle back and forth the style
[image]

Regardless of whether the white-space-collapse style is preserve or anything else; the last box will always collapse the whitespace whereas textArea or binding to a longTextArea field will not collapse whitespace:

[image]

I think you got the results you did because you bound all three components to the same SObject.field and since it is of type Text and one of the components was inputField, it smashed the controller value used by all three components to one with collapsed whitespace.

Note that VF `apex:inputField` behavior for a field of type Text  is, by, implicit definition, exactly the same behavior as a standard pageLayout Text field - you simply can't preserve multiple spaces.

Comment: I absolutely appreciate the effort and detail in which you digged into this...but I am still not sure if I understand what you are saying and why this happens. I need to convince a customer who believes that this is a bug that it actually is the way it ALWAYS was.

Comment: I'm with mLucci here - as for inputField bound to an sobject.field of type TEXT, this is always the way SFDC worked; furthermore, for Sobject.field of type long text area, if using the standard page layout, spaces are collapsed as well